# Update value in Teradata with different datatype Error 3754

Tags: sql, sql-update, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm trying to update a column value on Teradata , the source column are a varchar and the target a decimal (COD_ARTMDL to NUM_ARTAPP)
I tried to do a SET **NUM_ARTAPP = TO_NUMBER(COD_ARTMDL)**
But have an error :
**UPDATE Failed. 3754:  Precision error in FLOAT type constant or during implicit conversions.**
Can you help me with this ?
Thanks

[image: Source column]

[image: Target Column]

Comment: Sample data and code would certainly help. But most likely you need to explicitly cast your character field, not allow Teradata to do an implicit cast.

Comment: So you are explicitly converting the string to NUMBER and then trying to store it in a DECIMAL(18,0) field? Is there a reason you don't CAST directly to DECIMAL?

Comment: Hello , I tried to do a CAST AS DECIMAL(18) but still the same issue. Exemple of sample data in source '1400835968'

Comment: Your target column is defined as dec(18,0)?  `TO_NUMBER` will return decimal places.  Try running `select to_number('1400835968')`.

Comment: You might use `SELECT COD_ARTMDL FROM mytab WHERE TRYCAST(COD_ARTMDL AS DECIMAL(18,0)) IS NULL` to see the bad data.